# Convert object with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

How convert Request object to IRequest object with automapper?

This example not work. In new object IRequest all properties is null:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Request, IRequest>();
Mapper.CreateMap<RequestInfo, RequestInfo>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientInfo, ClientInfo>();


public class Request { 

    public RequestInfo requestInfo { get; set; }        

    public ClientInfo clientInfo { get; set; }

    public DocumentInfo documentInfo { get; set; }   

}

public interface IRequest { 

    RequestInfo RequestInfo { get; set; }        

    ClientInfo ClientInfo { get; set; }

    DocumentInfo DocumentInfo { get; set; }   

}
```

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work about it?

Comment: You don't show where you actually try to map to a destination object.

Comment: You should avoid prefixing a class with the I letter, because it's commonly used for interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Automapper maps by *property name*, not by *type name*.  Since the properties in your two classes have different names due to casing, you'll need to explicitly define the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Request, IRequest>()
      .ForMember(d => d.RequestInfo , m => m.MapFrom(s => s.requestInfo ))
      .ForMember(d => d.ClientInfo  , m => m.MapFrom(s => s.clientInfo  ))
      .ForMember(d => d.DocumentInfo, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.documentInfo))
```

Or you could just rename the properties in `Request` to be consistent.

As a side note, I would *not* use `IRequest` as a class name.  Types that start with `I` are almost universally assumed to be interfaces, not classes.

Comment: I have mapping from class to interface

Comment: @zrabzdn is that another question?